# Visual Studio host , The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous')

Tags: c#, wcf

i faced and error

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous') do not
>   allow those configured on the binding 'WebHttpBinding' ('Basic').

The problem occur  when i run the Service in VS.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceX_Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ServiceX.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator, ServiceX"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <!--<serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Basic"/>-->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBinding_Behavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>-->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceX.ServiceX" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceX_Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceX.IServiceX" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBinding_Behavior" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceX.IServiceX" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When i run  in IIS , it workk fine. When i run in Console app , it works fun. What is the difference with VS ? 
the following work fine, the same as config described  above

```
Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost/TestService");
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), serviceUri);


BasicHttpBinding basicHttp = new BasicHttpBinding();
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), basicHttp, "soap");

ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");


var contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IService));
contract.Namespace = "WCFServer";

var webHttpEndpoint = new WebHttpEndpoint(contract);
webHttpEndpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
var webHttpBinding = (WebHttpBinding)webHttpEndpoint.Binding;
webHttpBinding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
webHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(webHttpEndpoint);

//serviceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNameAuthentication();

foreach (var bh in serviceHost.Description.Behaviors)
{
    var serviceMetadata = bh as ServiceMetadataBehavior;
    if (serviceMetadata != null)
    {
        serviceMetadata.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    }

    var serviceDebug = bh as ServiceDebugBehavior;
    if (serviceDebug != null)
    {
        serviceDebug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false;
    }
}
serviceHost.Open();
Console.ReadLine();
serviceHost.Close();
```

In ISS Basic Authentication and Anonymous Authentication are allowed
IN VS Anonymous Authentication enabled

How come in Visual Studio the  WCF web project doesn't work , Console project and deployed in IIS web app work fine. What is the difference ?

I want to implement Basic Authentication in WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that IIS Express hasn't enabled the `BasicAuthentication` by default. As you know we need to enable `BasicAuthentication` to support WCF `BasicAuthentication`. IIS Express is configured with the `ApplicationHost.config` file. We should update the following values in the `ApplicationHost.config` to enable `BasicAuthentication`.

```
<security>
            <access sslFlags="None" />
            <applicationDependencies>
                <application name="Active Server Pages" groupId="ASP" />
            </applicationDependencies>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />
<!-- set to true –->
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
```

In VS2015 and above. The `ApplicationHost.config` locates in the below.

> Solution file directory(containing the Sln file)/.vs/solution
>   name/applicationhost.config

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.